# Unable to send AppleEvent to System Process

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I recently noticed that my app is no longer able to send system events like `kAESleep`, `kAEReallyLogOut` and `kAEShutDown`, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

All I can say is, it worked ~6 months ago when I last tested these particular options. I have probably upgraded Xcode and the OS itself since then, so perhaps something's changed under the hood.

The (non-throwing) error:
`2018-04-22 10:24:36.548501+1000 <APP-NAME>[15698:628777] AppleEvents: received mach msg which wasn't complex type as expected in getMemoryReference.`

My function looks like this (borrowed  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/90702):

```
private func sendSystemCommand(command: AEEventID) throws {
    var psn = ProcessSerialNumber(highLongOfPSN: UInt32(0), lowLongOfPSN: UInt32(kSystemProcess))
    let target = NSAppleEventDescriptor(descriptorType: typeProcessSerialNumber, bytes: &psn, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: psn))
    let event = NSAppleEventDescriptor(
        eventClass: kCoreEventClass,
        eventID: command,
        targetDescriptor: target,
        returnID: AEReturnID(kAutoGenerateReturnID),
        transactionID: AETransactionID(kAnyTransactionID)
    )
    _ = try event.sendEvent(options: [.defaultOptions], timeout: TimeInterval(kAEDefaultTimeout))
}
```

Implementation looks like this:

```
do {
    try self.sendSystemCommand(command: kAEShutDown)
    print("Shutting down")
} catch {
    print("Error sending `shut down` command to system")
}
```

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** After much back and forth, I believe this behaviour is caused by the app sandboxing system. I can observe the same issue by sending a system command like `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to shut down'`. The command works as expected from a Terminal shell, but returns an error when sent from my app.

I've been lead to believe that an app can request privileges to send system event commands, but I haven't been able to figure out how -- it doesn't seem overly well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` entitlement for `com.apple.systemevents`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>...</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <array>
    <string>com.apple.systemevents</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem to, and I make it with Objective C. like this

```
OSStatus SendAppleEventToSystemProcess(AEEventID EventToSend) {
AEAddressDesc targetDesc;
static const ProcessSerialNumber kPSNOfSystemProcess = { 0, kSystemProcess };
AppleEvent eventReply = { typeNull, NULL };
AppleEvent appleEventToSend = { typeNull, NULL };

OSStatus error = noErr;

error = AECreateDesc(typeProcessSerialNumber, &kPSNOfSystemProcess, sizeof(kPSNOfSystemProcess), &targetDesc);

if (error != noErr) {
    return error;
}

error = AECreateAppleEvent(kCoreEventClass, EventToSend, &targetDesc, kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID, &appleEventToSend);

AEDisposeDesc(&targetDesc);

if (error != noErr) {
    return error;
}

error = AESend(&appleEventToSend, &eventReply, kAENoReply, kAENormalPriority, kAEDefaultTimeout, NULL, NULL);
```

//    error = AESendMessage(&appleEventToSend, &eventReply, kAENormalPriority, kAEDefaultTimeout);

```
AEDisposeDesc(&appleEventToSend);

if (error != noErr) {
    return error;
}

AEDisposeDesc(&eventReply);
return error;
```

}

Comment: Like I mentioned in the update to my post, I believe this to be a Sandboxing issue. While I can't help you with much regarding Objective C, if you come across a solution, please post back

Comment: Yeah you're right, I can shutdown when the sandbox ON,But it can be shutdown when sandbox off.